# Can I power an Arduino with a computer's motherboard?

Tags: arduino-uno, power

I was thinking of using my Arduino to turn on and off a computer remotely. I would like to know if the 5v header pin on a computer's motherboard (which I’m using instead of a USB because the 5v pin provides a constant power supply) can power an Arduino UNO without frying it. If the Arduino can be powered where would the cable from the 5v motherboard pin go into the Arduino?
[image]

↑ These are the pins I would like to use

Comment: Can you post a picture or a description of this pin? Is it just on a USB header?

Comment: There is 5V at the power-header-pins, but I would assume there is a current limiting resistor somewhere on the MB. Better options are using either the internal usb-headers (which have fuses for extra protection). Or use one of the molex connectors used for powering CD-rom drives etc. (Red is 5V, black is GND).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to tap off of the +5VSB pin of the [ATX](http://pinouts.ru/Power/atxpower_pinout.shtml) or [BTX](http://pinouts.ru/Power/btx_mbpower_pinout.shtml) power supply connector and send it to the 5V pin on the Arduino. Where this will directly drive the VCC(5V) of the UNO.

[image]

Note that 5V of the USB basically drives the VCC directly, except through a MOSFET that acts as a blocking diode to prevent local VCC from flowing back to the 5V_USB.

---

Not sure if you are suggesting that the 5V USB is frying Arduino's. If so that is bad. If true; Fix that first.

---

That said (with good 5V usb) you should be able to find or configure (BIOS) so that a USB connector will remain powered, and allow a wake up from mouse movement. Hence a possible solution would be to use a Leonardo/Micro's Mouse emulation to do just that as to wake the PC, without any hardware mod's.

Freeduino Micro's are pretty cheap.

Comment: Applying power to the 5v header, will bypass the polyfuse. I personally would just cut up a USB cable and use the power and ground wires to connect to the PC's power.

Comment: I ended up using the cut up USB header method that Gerben said to power the arduino for anyone who wanted to know

Answer (score 0):

As stated by @mpflaga you can power your Arduino by the 5v power rail. As @ Gerben mentions in a comment, doing this will bypass the polyfuse. Because of this, I [create my own](https://www.virtuabotix.com/bareduino328-plus-regulate-your-bareduino/) Arduino for less than $10 (US) with a power regulator. Using a  `L7805ACP` will regulate the power.

Part List:

```
• 1 x P-DIP ATMEGA328P-PU programmed with Duemilanove Bootloader
• 3 x Through-Hole 22pF Capacitors (2 for crystal and 1 for Analog power smoothing)
• 1 x Through-Hole HC-49S 16 MHz Crystal (for clock)
• 1 x 5 Volt regulator (peak current 2 A, nominal )(L7805ACP
  Input Voltage = 7.5 to 18 V
  Output Voltage Low 4.8 Volts Nominal 5 Volts  High 5.2 Volts)
• 1 x 22 uF Capacitor (to stabilize power rail during rapid current draw.
```

[image: Homemade Arduino]